# Pretty Print Statement to String in Clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm trying to pretty print a `Clang` statement to a `string` so that the C/C++ code of the statement is printed. I do this in the following way:

```
//Generate string and string ostream.
string stmt;
raw_string_ostream stream(stmt);

//Get statement from ASTMatcher and print to ostream.
auto* statement = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::Expr>(types[VAR_STMT]);
statement->printPretty(stream, NULL, PrintingPolicy(LangOptions()));

//Flush ostream buffer.
stream.flush();
cout << statement << endl;
```

This code compiles and runs fine. However, when I run the following code, I get the address of the `statement` object printed to the `string`. For instance, when I run this code, I get the following as output:

```
0x3ccd598
0x3ccd5b0
0x3ccd728
0x3ccdc88
0x3ccdd08
```

There isn't really a lot of documentation about `printPretty(...)` in `Clang`'s documentation so what is the **correct** way to print the code of a `statement` to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I found while trying to get this to work is from a [Clang developers post](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/source-code-string-from-SourceRange-td4032732.html) from 2013.

Instead of:

```
//Generate string and string ostream.
string stmt;
raw_string_ostream stream(stmt);

//Get statement from ASTMatcher and print to ostream.
auto* statement = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::Expr>(types[VAR_STMT]);
statement->printPretty(stream, NULL, PrintingPolicy(LangOptions()));

//Flush ostream buffer.
stream.flush();
cout << statement << endl;
```

My code is now:

```
//Get the statement from the ASTMatcher
auto *statement = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::Expr>(types[VAR_STMT]);

//Get the source range and manager.
SourceRange range = statement->getSourceRange();
const SourceManager *SM = result.SourceManager;

//Use LLVM's lexer to get source text.
llvm::StringRef ref = Lexer::getSourceText(CharSourceRange::getCharRange(range), *SM, LangOptions());
cout << ref.str() << endl;
```

This approach does seem to work though I'm not too sure of any potential downsides.

Comment: What is 'result' here?

Comment: @aviator It is most likely a [`clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ast__matchers_1_1MatchFinder.html)`::MatchResult`, perhaps passed to the `check` method of a `clang::tidy::ClangTidyCheck`.

Comment: This merely prints the original text from the input file.  The [answer by Marwan N](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67788835/2659307) prints based on the AST structure, which is what "pretty print" usually means.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out that it's possible to print a statement into a string using a `raw_string_ostream`:

```cpp
// stmt is the statement you wish to print
string stmtToString(Stmt *stmt){
    clang::LangOptions lo;
    string out_str;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream outstream(out_str);
    stmt->printPretty(outstream, NULL, PrintingPolicy(lo));
    return out_str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be confusing yourself because of your similar variable names.  You have a variable `stmt` that is of type `string` and you have a variable `statement` that is (presumably) of type `clang::Stmt *`.  The `printPretty` call is modifying the `stream` variable, which writes to `stmt`, and not `statement`.  Then you print `statement`, the pointer to the clang type.  So naturally, a `cout` call for a pointer type writes the pointer's address.

Change your `cout` line to write out `stmt`, and you'll get what you're expecting.